# Is there exist countable union of half-open $(a,b]$ in Interval $(0,1]$

Tags: measure-theory

We know that $\mathbb{X} = (0,1]$,and $\mathcal{M} = \{\emptyset,\text{finite unions of disjoint intervals that are open on the left and closed on the right} \}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

However,if I let $\mathcal{M_1} = \{\emptyset,\text{countable unions of disjoint intervals that are open on the left and closed on the right} \}$, is $M_1$  a $\sigma$-algebra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't.

The intervals $(1-\frac1n,1-\frac1{n+1}]$, $n=1,2,\dots$ are disjoint, the countable union is $(0,1)$, whose complement in $(0,1]$ is the singleton $\{1\}$ not in $\mathcal{M}_1$.

Answer (score 0):

No. $\bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty} (\frac 1 2-\frac  1 n, \frac 1 2-\frac  1 {n+1}] \cup (\frac 1  2, 1]=(0,1]\setminus \{\frac 1 2\}$. The left side is in your class. If it is  a sigma algebra then $\{\frac 1 2\}$ would be in the class, but this is not true.